# Make div appear on active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with a UL that controls the filtering of my portfolio items, using the .active class I changed the active color of the filters. But I also have a DIV that is below the filters and I want it to appear and disappear when each filter is clicked. I am just having trouble with the CSS selectors!

**My HTML:**

```
<!--=== Portfolio Filter ===-->
<div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills col-xs-12">
        <li class="filter" data-filter="all">Show Me TV</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter="print">Conventions</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter="web">Elite</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!--=== Description ===-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="category-description">
            all description
        </span>
        <span class="category-description">
            conventions description
        </span>
        <span class="category-description">
            elite description
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.category-description { visibility:hidden; }
#portfolio .nav > li.active { color:#e21f24; }
#portfolio .nav > li.active + .category-description { visibility:visible; }
```

Can anyone help out a bit?

Comment: If you want to take control with pure CSS, you need to add class `active` to your `row` element, for example `active-web` and then the `+` selector works: `.row.active-web + .container .category-description`. Otherwise, you need JavaScript...

Comment: Does each filter have its own description? You have three filter, but one description. When the description will show? By which filter?

Comment: Yes each filter has its own description, each should show below its filter, and when switched previous filter should be hidden and new one needs to show up below new filter. Hope all that make sense I updated HTML with how I think it should go

Comment: How do you control the `active` and `click` of filters? Please paste your js code.

Comment: I am using [mixitup.js](https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup) for the filtering I believe mixitup already uses the .active class

Comment: Yes, it does. I believe the simple and clean solution is moving your `description` elements inside your `li` elements and play with their styles to achieve the result you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple and clean solution, is changing your markup and move the `description` element inside your `li` element:

```
<li class="filter" data-filter="print">
    Conventions
    <div class="description">Conventions Description</div>
</li>
```

Now you can take control of `description` element:

```
.description { display: none; }
li.active .description { display: block; }
```

*(you need to control the result with playing with CSS to achieve what you want)*

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nyrsp9nb/).

Comment: Ah okay this is the same way I did it, but I am having some issues with the positioning. The description will go under my portfolio items if it is too long, instead of pushing the content down. And I can only get the descriptions to display left aligned instead of in the center

Comment: I believe it's possible to achieve **exactly** what you want, but it's complex. I think its worth to do it, instead of involving with JS and change the algorithm of mixitup...

Comment: Ah so the whole left align issue cannot be fixed with CSS?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said it can be fixed with CSS, but maybe it's complex... `;)`

Comment: Small hint and ill give you the accepted answer lol ive literally been trying to figure this out for an hour now :/ positioned and aligned every way I can think of!

Comment: I don't know what do you want exactly, but here is a sample of center text align: [JSFiddle Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/nyrsp9nb/1/), [JSFiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nyrsp9nb/2/).